Why can't I initialise AnyPublisher property in a class?
I want to initialise all properties in my class. I don't want isEmptyPublisher property to start working when it is first accessed. I want it to start working as soon as it is initialised.
Why can't I initialise an AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> property in a class in this fashion?
class MyClass {
    private let name: String
    @Published private(set) var friends = [String]()

    let isEmptyPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.isEmptyPublisher = $friends.map(\.isEmpty).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

}

The compiler produces this error:

'self' used in property access '$friends' before all stored properties
are initialized


'self.isEmptyPublisher' not initialized

I have to write it like this:
class MyClass {
    private let name: String
    @Published private(set) var friends = [String]()

//    let isEmptyPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>

    private(set) lazy var isEmptyPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> = {
        return $friends.map(\.isEmpty).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }()

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
//        self.isEmptyPublisher = $friends.map(\.isEmpty).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

}


I want the AnyPublisher to start working immediately upon initialisation rather than when it is first accessed. Generally, speaking, I like to initialise all properties rather than use lazy as a "workaround".

Why don't you define isEmptyPublisher  as computed property?

Because it will be creating a new AnyPublisher every time when it is accessed and it doesn't make sense. It should be created one and used as needed.

You cannot use the $ syntax for the @Published property in the initialiser, because @Published is special in that it uses the reference of its enclosing class. Not every property wrapper does this, though. You might get an idea how such property wrapper can be implemented here in this article: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/accessing-a-swift-property-wrappers-enclosing-instance/

If you were to adopt the lazy pattern (your objections notwithstanding), one could simplify it by eliminating the closure initializer:
class MyClass {
    private let name: String
    @Published private(set) var friends = [String]()

    private(set) lazy var isEmptyPublisher = $friends.map(\.isEmpty).eraseToAnyPublisher()

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

Or even just:
class MyClass {
    private let name: String
    @Published private(set) var friends = [String]()

    private(set) lazy var isEmptyPublisher = $friends.map(\.isEmpty)

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

Using lazy is my “go to” approach for these scenarios.

You can use the underlying data instead:
self.isEmptyPublisher = _friends.projectedValue.map(\.isEmpty).eraseToAnyPublisher()

